# Need a If and else statement and a new page

Tags: javascript, html, validation, if-statement

This is what i need help with! 
My project needs a If and else statement for the Age part! 
and then send the person who has validated correctly to a new page.. I currently have a page but that is just something that is in my USB

also need to explain how its is validating

Please help

```js
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") 
 {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

 var Age = document.forms["myForm"]["Age"].value;
    if (Age == null || Age == "") {
        alert("Has to be a number between 1 and 150");
        return false; 

    }

    var Email = document.forms["myForm"]["Email"].value;
    if (Email == null || Email == "") {
        alert("Make sure it is the correct Email format");
        return false; 
 
 } 
 
 var myCheck = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
    if (myCheck == false) {
        alert("Have to tick box to proceed");
        return false; 
    }  
 
 
  
 
 
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="file:///G:/Welcome.html"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="Age"> 
Email: <input type="text" name="Email">
<br>checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="myCheck"> </br>
<input type="submit" value="click">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need no check for `null`, because `element.value` returns a string, which is either empty `''` or has some content. a small other hint, please use a small letter for the first letter of a variable. first uppercase letter shows usually a class.

Comment: So you want a to place an `if` condition into your function... but what are the conditions? `If(age?????)`

Comment: if you send the validated user to a new page, all of the form data will be lost. Aren't you going to post it back to the server?

Comment: Why are you assuming nobody lives over 150 years old? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the if clause with the age check.

```
var age = document.forms["myForm"]["Age"].value;
if (age == "" || age < 1 || age > 150) {
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    alert("Has to be a number between 1 and 150");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to parse the value as an int? `var age =parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["Age"].value);`

Comment: in this case the value is implicit converted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd parse the value of the form into a number and then I'd check its range:

```
var age = Number(document.forms["myForm"]["Age"].value) || 0;

if (age < 1 || age > 150) {
        alert("Has to be a number between 1 and 150");
        return false;
}
```

Why convert to number and put `Number(document.forms["myForm"]["Age"].value) || 0`?

The reason is simple: imagine that a malicious user put in your form the value "NaN". If you didn't do this check, the value of age would be NaN and it'd pass your check (`NaN < 1` is `false` and `NaN > 150` is `false` too).

This way, if a user put "NaN" in the form, the guard would transform it into 0, the alert would trigger and the function would return false.